# Getting error SP2-0158: unknown SET option

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

**I am getting error while running my script**

SP2-0158: unknown SET option "errorlogging"
SP2-0158: unknown SET option "echo"
SP2-0158: unknown COLUMN option "ENTMAP"
SP2-0158: unknown COLUMN option "ENTMAP"
SP2-0158: unknown COLUMN option "ENTMAP"
SP2-0158: unknown COLUMN option "ENTMAP"
SP2-0158: unknown COLUMN option "ENTMAP"
Connected

SP2-0158: unknown SET option "markup"
**Loading count**
SP2-0158: unknown SET option "markup"

no rows selected

Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Data Mining

### and Real Application Testing options

My Script is:-

```
SET VERIFY OFF 
    SET ECHO OFF MARKUP HTML ON SPOOL ON PREFORMAT OFF ENTMAP ON -
HEAD "<TITLE>File Loading Monitoring Report</TITLE> -
<h1>File Loading Monitoring Report: &_Date</h1> -
<STYLE type='text/css'> -
<!-- BODY {background: white} --> -
</STYLE>" -
BODY "TEXT='black'" -
TABLE "WIDTH='70%' BORDER='5'"

column "StartTime" heading "StartTime" format 99 ENTMAP OFF
column "NumberOfFiles" heading "NumberOfFiles" format 999,999,999 ENTMAP OFF
column "Volume_GB" heading "Volume_GB" format 999,999,999 ENTMAP OFF
column "ClusterName" heading "ClusterName" format 999,999,999 ENTMAP OFF
column "IPAddress" heading "IPAddress" format 999,999,999 ENTMAP OFF

define connStr = 'OWNER/_OWNER@abc.com:2521/abc.com';

SPOOL d:/deployments/One/content/FileVolume.html

----------------------------------
-- GetQueue
----------------------------------
connect &connStr    
SET PAGESIZE 200
SET MARKUP HTML ENTMAP OFF

PROMPT <font size=4 color="blue"><b>Loading count</b></a></font>


SET MARKUP HTML ENTMAP ON   

select to_char(df.starttime, 'YYYY-MM-DD') StartTime, dc.clustername, round(sum(df.filelength)/1024/1024/1024,0) Volume_GB, count(*) NumberOfFiles
from files df join fileloadstatus dfs on df.fileid = dfs.fileid
    where df.starttime > sysdate - 14 and df.starttime < sysdate +1 and dc.clusterid = 81 and p.name like '%Stage1%'
group by to_char(df.starttime, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), dc.clustername
order by 1 desc, 2 asc;

SET MARKUP HTML ENTMAP OFF

disconnect;

SPOOL OFF
exit
```

Comment: How are you running the script?  SQLPlus? SQLDeveloper? TOAD? ????